# Tkinter чем отличается от graphics

Tags: tkinter, графика

Слабо знаком со всей питоновской экосистемой. Но хочу на питоне делать относительно простые экспериментальные симуляции. И задался вопросом, чем отрисовывать. Нашел библиотеку graphics.py, покопался в ней и увидел, что она написана с использованием tkinter.
В ткинтере я так понимаю упор на GUI, а не рисование, когда в graphics.py все упрощено а интерфейсы создавать нельзя. Это все отличия, и graphics просто казуальная насадка на tkinter или есть еще какие то отличия?

Comment: Никогда не сталкивался с graphics.py, но если сделано поверх Tkinter, значит там скорее всего просто упрощается то, что можно сделать через обычный Canvas. Ничего сверх того, что можно сделать просто через Tkinter там не будет.

Comment: А что за канвас? Это то, поверх чего сделан ткинтер, или как? Я слышал о нем только в контексте веб разработкии

Comment: Нет, это просто объект-холст (canvas буквально переводится как "холст"), на котором в Tkinter можно рисовать. Он "внутри" Tkinter, но не Tkinter поверх него. В веб-разработке свой canvas, с canvas в Tkinter никак не связан.